# How can I limit / restrict the plotted relationships in a neo4j graph query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dijkstra, neo4j-apoc

I created a Graph Database in neo4j, my main interest with this database is to find the cheapest teleport paths between towns on a MMORPG world. Here is the script to build up the database:

https://gist.github.com/sergio-bobillier/1effa24d406e84afe0976277d04c0218

As you can see the nodes in the graph have a LOT of connections between them, this is because all the major towns are connected between them.

I use the Dijkstra algorithm to get the cheapest path like this:

`MATCH (s {name: 'Talking Island Village'}), (t {name: 'Town of Oren'})
  CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(s, t, 'HAS_A_PORT_TO>', 'cost') YIELD path, weight
  RETURN path LIMIT 1`

This works great, the algorithm returns the correct path but there is something that bothers me, when the neo4j browser plots the path at first it plots only the path returned by the algorithm, however it quickly "completes" the graph by plotting all the connections between the nodes (even those not included in the path returned by Dijkstra), which makes the plotted graph really confusing:

[image: plotted graph]

How can I keep node4j from plotting all these extra relationships and include only the path returned by the Dijkstra algorithm?

Comment: It looks like that in the neoj browser settings you need to turn off the option `Browser Settings` -> `Graph Visualization` -> `Connect result nodes`

Comment: @stdob-- That did the trick, thanks :) You should put that as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that in the neoj browser settings you need to turn off the option `Browser Settings -> Graph Visualization -> Connect result nodes`.